# Golang JSON Marshaling

Tags: go

I'm trying to marshal an array into a string, separating all elements with newlines. I'm running out of memory and think about a more efficient way to do this.

```
buffer := ""
for _, record := range all_data {

    body, _ := json.Marshal(record)
    buffer += string(body) + "\n" // i run out of memory here
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to append a newline character to a byte array? Right now I'm casting via `string(body)`, but I think that this operation allocates a lot of memory (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: How are you going to use `buffer` later in your app?

Comment: You can change buffer to a slice of byte and use the builtin func append(...), but if you're trying to append GB of data you can get out of memory anyway.

Comment: Consider to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863164/how-to-analyse-golang-memory

Comment: `string` is constant in Golang. It's better to use `bytes.Buffer` instead and also other language which `string` is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data isn't inherently too big for the computer it's running on, the problem is likely the inefficient building of that string. Instead you should be using a `bytes.buffer` and then callings it's `String()` method. Here's an example;

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer

for _, record := range all_data {
    body, _ := json.Marshal(record)
    buffer.Write(body)
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
}

fmt.Println(buffer.String())
```

Comment: Heh, I was just about to post this as I just changed my code to use bytes.Buffer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to evanmcdonnal's answer: you don't even need an intermediate buffer created by json.Marshal:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
enc := json.NewEncoder(&buf)
for _, record := range allData {
  if err := enc.Encode(record); enc != nil {
    // handle error
  }
  buf.WriteString("\n") // optional
}
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5K9Oj0Xbjaa

Comment: Inside the for loop, the check should be `err != nil`.