# Current RSS slowly increasing while heap is not

Tags: go

This is a graph of current RSS. The decrease in the beginning is due to a restart, and then it seems to slowly increase infinitely.
[image: Current RSS]

This is the heap. The idle heap seems to also be on a slowly upwards trend. The non-idle heap seems to stay down.
[image: Heap]

Do I have a memory leak, or does this seem normal?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863164/how-to-analyse-golang-memory. Eg: you can only tell if you have a leak after a memory profile.

Comment: A memory profile doesn't necessarily point to a leak (usually it doesn't), but you do need to use the memory statistics from within the process as the external measurements don't necessarily reflect what the process claims. This graph looks like it's approaching a sustained max, does it ever increase more? What does gctrace say is happening at that point? What are the runtime memory stats?