# Count heap objects by type

Tags: go, profiling

I'm looking for a way to count all live objects in heap, grouped by type. Seeing the size of the objects would be a bonus.

*Use case:* See why my application needs 36 GB of heap while the size of the data it's holding should be only 5 GB.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do it with `pprof`. Looks like it only counts allocations, not objects in heap.

In VisualVM (for JVM), a memory snapshot shows this information straight away:

[image: VisualVM objects list]

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863164/how-to-analyze-golang-memory

Comment: I don't think there is any way to see heap objects grouped by type. I'm not aware of any way to see live heap objects at all actually - I don't think Go indexes memory that way. You can use a profiler to see where in the code memory allocations happen, and from that infer what type of objects are being allocated often.